# What controls timeout of COM calls?

Tags: com

Our software can communicate over COM with Excel. An example is that Excel calls a COM function which causes our software to respond with results. However, if it takes our software more than around 3 minutes to calculate those results then the COM reference is dropped for some reason.

Is this just the nature of COM (to timeout if it doesn't receive a response to a call after a certain time) or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM doesn't have in-call timeout. If you start a call and the server enters an infinite loop while handling it the call lasts forever unless there's a communication problem between the client and the COM server.

However there're [timeouts for network connection problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255198). With the symptoms you describe it looks like some communication problem.

Comment: We've tried this with Excel and our software running on the same machine and we saw the same problem. So there was no network connections involved. Can you think of anything that we might be missing which could cause a problem with the call?

Comment: Turns out that the problem we were seeing was caused by our application thread being blocked while waiting on the COM call to return. The Windows API message queue for our application got to a point where it was completely full and then we saw an error.